# cannot establish jdbc in netbeans. error-login failed

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to establish a JDBC in Netbeans but there's some problem.

[image]

ERROR msgs:

> Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:sqlserver://HARSHS-PC\MSSQLSERVER;databaseName=mydb1 using com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
>  (**Cannot open database "mydb1" requested by the login. The login failed.** ClientConnectionId:b907cd41-799f-472e-b953-da1fbff24e36)

The username and password are correct for sure.
I am using MS SQL Server 18, java 16, NetBeans 12.3

Please suggest some possible solutions.

Comment: Seems like either _mydb1_ doesn't exist on the server or the _aa_ SQL Login doesn't have a mapping to a Database User in it.

Comment: *"I am using MS SQL Server 18"* SQL Server 18 hasn't been released, or even annouced yet, we're only on version 15 at the moment; SQL Server 2019.

Comment: As for the error, what is the true authentication error in the SQL Server's logs?

Comment: I wonder if `aa` is a typographic error of `sa` @AlwaysLearning ... 

Comment: In your previous question on the same topic, you were connecting to an EXPRESS instance (not the default) and you WERE using the sa login. Now it seems you have changed connection information for some reason - explain and clarify. Or perhaps just PAY ATTENTION to what you are doing?

Comment: @Larnu username is aa and not sa

Comment: @Larnu I meant microsoft SQL server management studio 18

Comment: OK, so what about the error in the error logs? We still need that.

Comment: @SMor I have already mentioned that the username and the password are correct and the instance name here is MSSQLSERVER ty

Comment: @Larnu how can I access error log

Comment: One way is in the Management Node in the object explorer in SSMS.

Comment: I think it is related to mapping issue and I am not able to enable the sa user

Comment: @Larnu okay one min let me check

Comment: @Larnu msgs- login failed for user 'aa'  Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'mydb1' . client [ 192.198.1.109]

Comment: idk how but i tried this time and it worked

Comment: ty everyone ty @Larnu ty AlwaysLearning, ty SSor

Comment: there's another problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/67744578/16043237